Locating the "Yan-king-fu" text, allegedly dating to 764
Within the Encyclopedia Iranica some French research papers are cited that allude to a Chinese source text by "Yan-king-fu". The relevance is that the days of the week were written in Sogdian:

The planetary week was introduced in China by the Manichean Sogdians
with the original Iranian names of the planets (Chavannes and Pelliot,
1913, pp. 100-302). The oldest recorded document was written in 764 by
Yan-king-fu, where the weekdays are named in Iranian—in the language
of Hu as called by the Chinese, which later M. F. K. Müller proved to
be Sogdian (Müller, 1907; Chavannes and Pelliot, 1913, p. 166). In the
Chinese calendar of the ninth and tenth centuries the names of the
seven planets are noted as corresponding to the seven days of the
week, Sunday is marked in red. This shows clearly the cultural
influence of the Sogdian immigrants in Chinese astronomical documents,
starting from the T’ang dynasty and continuing later. Müller’s
reconstruction of these words indicates a dating prior to the time
evidenced in written texts; that is, the borrowing occurred before the
eighth century. Thus Chin. mi < *m’it/m’ir reflects Sogdian mīr for
Sunday; mo < *mak, Sogdian māx for Monday; Yun-han < * ’wnx’n, Sogdian
wanxān for Tuesday;

I'd like to examine this text if it is digitized anywhere. The researches seem to be using a form of Pinyin when they refer to the Chinese "mi". The philological connection, as the 20th century researchers argue, is that mi relates to Mihr, and Mihr was Middle Persian for Avestan Mithra.
I encountered difficulty in finding the author/the identity of this "Yan-king-fu".
I did at least confirm that the "Hu" allegedly referring to Sogdians is the character "胡". But this advances matters very little. I'm interested in uncovering which character was used for "mi".
Question
Is there indeed a Chinese text written by Yan-king-fu that has a treatment of the days of the week and does Yan-king-fu himself have a Chinese name?
Relevant page: https://iranicaonline.org/articles/hafta-week-history-of-the-weeky-calendar-in-iran-1

@GarethRees Yes, the article was a bit confusing for those reasons. Thanks for pointing out the source though, great find. Looks to be written entirely in Sogdian in the Pahlavi script, seems there won't be any Chinese characters after all.  Would still be interested in the identity of Yan King Fu, which sounds like a name that might have Chinese characters.

Never mind, I found exactly the table where they show that morphology. Was too many languages, particularly the German that was tripping me up. Thanks again!

@GarethRees All of their abbreviations are spelled out online.

Is there enough info in the comments that can be turned into an answer that can be preserved and voted on?

When looking for the basis of a claim in an academic document, the first step is to follow the references. The Encyclopedia Iranica article on Hafta “week” is well-referenced, and the claim that “the oldest recorded document [in Chinese describing the planetary week] was written in 764 by Yan-king-fu” is cited to “Müller, 1907” and “Chavannes and Pelliot, 1913, p. 166”. Looking in the references section of the Iranica article, we find that these are:

E. Chavannes and P. Pelliot, “Un Traité Manichéen retrouvé en Chine,” JA 1911, pp. 101–201; 1913, pp. 99–199, 261–394.
F. W. K. Müller, “Die Persischen Kalenderausdrucke in Chinesischen Tripitaka,” SPAW, 1907, pp. 458–65.

Here JA and SPAW are abbreviations for Journal asiatique and Sitzungsberichte der Königlich Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften respectively. The Encyclopedia Iranica has a list of abbreviations, but this is not linked from the article. You might guess that there would be a list of abbreviations somewhere on the site and go searching for it. Or you could enter the article titles on Google Scholar and then click on the “Cite” link under the appropriate hit to get the full reference. (My personal opinion is that journal abbreviations are an unnecessary form of academic gate-keeping; formerly they were necessary in order to conserve space when publishing on paper, but maintaining the practice when publishing online serves no useful purpose.)
In the case of Müller (1907), the Encyclopedia Iranica has given us a little challenge by putting a typo in the title of the paper—it should be “im Chinesischen Tripitaka”, not “in”. But once that’s corrected, it’s straightforward to find the paper by doing a full-text search for the title on the Internet Archive. However, the paper itself does not discuss the Yan-king-fu text, but rather addresses the origin of the Chinese words for the planetary weekdays, arguing that these come from Sogdian, and not, as suggested by Éduard Huber, from Persian. Müller includes a facsimile of a “Manichaean–Sogdian calendar fragment” (table 6) but this is in the Manichaean script and the Sogdian language, and so is not the Yan-king-fu text, as we expect that to be in Chinese.
In the case of Chavannes and Pelliot (1913), Google Scholar links directly to the scan of the book on Google Books. A small difficulty arises because the book has two sets of page numbers. In this case, we want page 166 of the original journal version, which is page 190 of the book. Here we encounter another small difficulty, which is that Chavannes and Pelliot are using a different transliteration of the name: where Encyclopedia Iranica has the transliteration “Yan-king-fu”, Chavannes and Pelliot have “Yang King-fong”. On page 192 Chavannes and Pelliot write:

M. Huber a cité quatre ouvrages […] Le plus ancien des quatre ouvrages dont la date soit certaine est donc le dernier, intitulé 文殊師利菩薩及諸仙所說吉凶時日善惡宿曜經 Wen chou che li p’ou sa ki tchou sien so chouo ki hiong che je chan ngo sou yao king, ou Sūtra prononcé par le bodhisattva Mañjuçrī et les sages et les mansions heureux et malheureux.† Cet ouvrage fut traduit en 759 par Amoghavajra, originaire du Nord de l’Inde, et la traduction fut mise au point et annotée en 764 par un disciple d’Amoghavajra, nommé Yang King-fong.
Éduard Huber has cited four works […] The oldest of the four works of which the date is certain is thus the last, titled 文殊師利菩薩及諸仙所說吉凶時日善惡宿曜經 Wen chou che li p’ou sa ki tchou sien so chouo ki hiong che je chan ngo sou yao king, or Sutra delivered by the bodhisattva Manjushri and the sages and the fortunate and and unfortunate [lunar] mansions.† This work was translated in 759 by Amoghavajra, a native of northern India, and the translation was completed and annotated in 764 by a disciple of Amoghavajra, named Yang King-fong.
Édouard Chavannes & Paul Pelliot (1913). Un traité manichéen retrouvé en Chine, pp. 191–192. Paris: Imprimérie Nationale.
† Chavannes and Pelliot have mangled the title of the work here; see Huber below.

This seems to be the work we are looking for, and we expect to find more details in the cited work by Éduard Huber. The citation to Huber is in note (1) on page 166, which says just “B.E.F.E-O., VI, 39–43”. Looking at the table of “principal cited works” on page 11, the journal abbreviation decodes to Bulletin de l’École française d’Extrême-Orient. By searching on the Internet Archive, we can find volume 6 of this journal, where the relevant passage is as follows:

Enfin un passage analogue se trouve dans un quatrième ouvrage, le 文殊師利菩薩及諸仙所說吉凶時日善惡宿曜經 Wen-chou-che-li p’ou-sa ki tchou sien souo chouo ki hiong che je chan ngo siu yao king, Sutra prononcé par le bodhisattva Mañjuçrī et les Sages sur les époques et les jours fastes et nefastes, sur les planétes et les naksatra heureux et malheureux
(Nanjio,† Catalogue, Nᵒ 1355; Trip. de Tòkyò, XIV, pp. 59–65); il fut traduit en chinois en l’an 759 par Amoghavajra, originaire du Nord de l’Inde. Amoghavajra est bien connu comme introducteur en Chine des doctrines tantriques. il confia la rédaction définitive et l’annotation de cet ouvrage à son disciple 楊景風 Yang King-fong qui acheva son travail la seconde année de la période 廣徳 kouang-to,‡ en l’an 764. La passage que nous allons citer est une note que Yang King-fong a ajouté au chapitre qui traite de l’influence qu’exercent les sept planètes sur la destinée des hommes (loc. cit., p. 62 vᵒ):
Finally, an analogous passage is found in a fourth work, the 文殊師利菩薩及諸仙所說吉凶時日善惡宿曜經 Wen-chou-che-li p’ou-sa ki tchou sien souo chouo ki hiong che je chan ngo siu yao king, Sutra delivered by the bodhisattva Manjushri and the sages on good and bad times and days, on the planets and the fortunate and unfortunate nakshatras [lunar mansions] (Nanjio,† Catalogue, Nᵒ 1355; Trip. de Tòkyò, XIV, pp. 59–65); it was translated into Chinese in the year 759 by Amoghavajra, a native of northern India. Amoghavajra is well known as the introducer of Tantric doctrines into China. He entrusted the final editing and annotation of this work to his disciple 楊景風 Yang King-fong, who completed his task in the second year of the 廣徳 kouang-to period,‡ in the year 764. The passage that we are going to quote is a note that Yang King-fong added to the chapter which deals with the influence that the seven planets exert on human destiny (loc. cit., p. 62 vᵒ):
Éduard Huber (1906). ‘Études de littérature bouddhique’. Bulletin de l’École française d’Extrême-Orient volume 6, p. 41. Hanoi: F.-H. Schneider.
† Buddhist scholar Nanjo Bunyu (1849–1927). ‡ Now usually transliterated as “guǎngdé”, this refers to the early years of the reign of Emperor Daizong of Tang.

Huber quotes the Chinese text on pages 41–42 and translates it into French. The character used for mi is 密. To further investigate the origin of this text, we would need to find the cited work by Nanjo Bunyu, but I will stop here.

Similar text can be found in Wikipedia (Chinese version) as well (https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%98%9F%E6%9C%9F), 楊景風 is Yang King-fong in traditional Chinese. And its simplified Chinese form is 杨景风.

And Yan-king-fu should be same as Yang King-fong, just another way to spell the Chinese name in English. BTW, the Japanese language still uses planet names as days of week

@SilentSojourner It's the same in English, e.g. "Tuesday" is from Tiw, the Old English name for the god Týr, the Germanic equivalent of Mars.

@Sillent SojournerWhat's remarkable though is how different it is from the 七曜 system. Sunday in that framework is 日曜日, however, under this Sogdian transliteration, Sunday would be more like "密日" -- a more direct philological connection to Mihr/Mithra.
